# How to install "libproj-dev" on mac os x

Tags: macos, rubygems, proj

I am trying to install proj4rb on a Mac Mavericks (gem install proj4rb) but get the
following error:

```
----- Error Message
checking for proj_api.h... yes
checking for pj_init() in -lproj... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling projrb.c
projrb.c:2:22: error: projects.h: No such file or directory


----- End Error Message
```

I know the problem. It is requiring the header files which would be "libproj-dev" on linux.
I am new to mac so I wonder if somebody can help me out using either brew or macport.

To sum up, I need to install "libproj-dev" equivalent package for Mac.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You can install it via brew with

```
brew install proj
```